# Finding large primes in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, primes

I'm quite new to Mathematica and I am trying to find large prime numbers that can be written using only the digits 0, 1, 2 and 3 and more than half of these digits have to be 0. For example 100003 would qualify.

I was thinking of using the Prime[n] function with a bunch if "If" statements, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of going about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Neither 1000 nor 20001 are prime, though... Wouldn't 100003 (which is prime) be a better example? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Thanks for the observation, I'll rectify that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a good answer ask this question at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

For an answer of sorts, read on ...

The function

```
myTestQ[num_Integer] := 
   And[DigitCount[num][[10]] > Plus @@ DigitCount[num][[1 ;; 3]], PrimeQ[num]]
```

returns `True` when it's passed an integer which (i) has more `0` digits than `1`s,`2`s, and `3`s and (ii) is prime.  `And` evaluates its arguments in order and short-circuits so should avoid testing the primality of a number whose digit counts are not right.

In practice your computation time will be dominated by primality testing; generating and throwing away a lot of integers with the wrong digit counts is inexpensive enough that you can ignore the inefficiencies in that part of the program.

Now to test a range of integers composed of only `0,1,2,3` digits.  There's a whole family of integers using only those digits, namely all integers when written in base-4.  So lets generate those:

```
IntegerString[Range[lo, hi, 2], 4]
```

This will generate strings representing all the base-4 integers from the `lo`-th to the `hi`-th in steps of 2 (you're not going to be interested in any even numbers).  For example

```
IntegerString[Range[1, 13, 2], 4]
```

produces

```
{"1", "3", "11", "13", "21", "23", "31"}
```

that is, the 1st, 3rd, 5th, ..., 13th base-4 numbers in string form.  Of course, you'll need them back as integers to test them, and we'll use `ToExpression` for that.

Mash it all together and you get something like

```
Select[ToExpression[IntegerString[Range[lo, hi, 2], 4]], myTestQ]
```

replacing `lo` and `hi` with whatever you like, but making sure `lo` is an odd number.

Answer (score 3):

You could go fishing. First generate large integers of the required pattern and then test them for primality. I don't have Mathematica, but here is a quick and dirty implementation in Python:

```
import random

def rand_candidate(n):
    #assumes n > 4
    while True:
        s = [random.choice(['1','2','3'])]
        for i in range(n-2):
            s.append(random.choice(['0','0','0','1','2','3']))
        s.append(random.choice(['1','3']))
        if s.count('0') > n/2: return int(''.join(s))
```

The previous function starts by selecting a non-zero leading digit, then picks the intermediate digits in a way which is biased to 0, then picks the final digit to make it odd, checking that the overall result has the requisite number of zeros.

For a primality test, I got lazy and just used a Fermat pseudo-prime test. The following test was used (and is maybe still used) for the PGP implementation of RSA. It has a very low probability of certifying a composite number as prime. In Mathematica you would of course have recourse to more sophisticated tests:

```
def prob_prime(n):
    tests = [2,3,5,7]
    return all(n % p != 0 and pow(p,n-1,n) == 1 for p in tests)
```

Putting them together:

```
def go_fishing(n):
    while True:
        p = rand_candidate(n)
        if prob_prime(p): return p
```

Typical output:

```
>>> go_fishing(20)
23002001032200000101
>>> go_fishing(100)
1100200103020002000000000020232222230321210000103030031022000000200001001300020010012122020101020113
```

The computer algebra system Derive (which I do have on my machine) certifies both of the above as prime.